# How to create Custom action project with WIX 2.0

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix2

I have installed WIX 2.0 (and Votive). I need to create user defined custom actions using the Custom action project. I found the custom action project template in VS2008 when WIX 3.0 is installed. Now, I couldn't find any template in VS2005 with WIX 2.0.

Can anyone please let me know how can I create a custom action project (class with some custom action).. like this

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult InstallItem1(Session session)
```

I think Microsoft.WindowsInstaller and Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller are the references required (not sure) to create such methods but i couldnt find them in my machine.

---

I managed to create a Custom Action project (just a Class Library with one class and the Custom Action methods) by referring 'Microsoft.WindowsInstaller' dll. But facing problem in executing that dll..

```
<Custom Action='_InstallItem2' After='_InstallItem1'/>

<CustomAction Id='_InstallItem2'
  BinaryKey='CustomActionLibrary.dll'   
  DllEntry='InstallItem2'
  Impersonate='yes'
  Execute='immediate'
  Return='check' />

<Binary Id='CustomActionLibrary.dll'
  SourceFile='C:\WIX\CustomActionLibrary.dll' />
```

There is a method called 'InstallItem2' marked as [CustomAction] in that dll.. But facing the error:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run(...)

Any idea why this error is coming?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is actually a DTF (deployment tools foundation) project, but DTF was first released with WiX 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info Freund, 
Actually i need to do some action as part of installer which is not present in WIX custom actions (some application specific functions..similar to Custom Actions in WIX 3.0). How can i do this in WIX 2.0.
Any idea?

Comment: I have no experience with 2.0, but I'm assuming that you can still create C++ custom action projects through the wizard. If that doesn't work, you can always create a custom action DLL yourself and call it from the installer.

Comment: Thanks for your time Freund,
I've tried creating custom action dll with 'Class library' template, but 

[CustomAction] 
public static ActionResult InstallItem1(Session session)

is giving errors.. unable to find references for Session, ActionResult etc..i think 'Microsoft.WindowsInstaller' and 'Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller' dlls are required for that.

Comment: These namespaces are part of DTF, which you need if you want to use C#. For what I'm suggesting, you need to create an unmanaged C++ class library. But why not simply use WiX 3.0?

Comment: Our installer is going to be integrated with client's installer (on WIX 2.0)..so we should use 2.0 only :(

Comment: How will the integration be performed? If you're creating a merge module, there's no problem creating it with 3.0 and integrating it into a 2.0 MSI (in fact, you can replace it with any other MSI/MSM authoring tool on both sides)

Comment: It will be a separate installer, but the build machine has wix 2.0 only and client is specific about the version.